# Eliminating current playing track sound in recording track

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-audio, remoteio

I am looking to use RemoteI/O for audio recording and playing.I am very poor to understand core audio, because of that I followed [Amazing Audio open source](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/).So far I can able to Record and play with the same code, now I am trying to record through microphone and play though iphone speaker to avoid mixing of two audios while using simultaneous audio playing and recording.

I have seen many posts in Stack Overflow that my question is duplicate, but I couldn't find exact answer for my problem. But I have hope to implement by seeing [Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals.html).

**Questions:**

1. How to implement simultaneous recording and playing using RemoteI/O?

   Answer: Done using Amazing Audio Engine
2. How to stop mixing of two audios while playing my recorded audio and recording another track? (Eliminating audio samples which is playing through my app)
3. How to change the recording through microphone and playing through Iphone speakers?

Comment: +1 for the link to the amazing the amazing audio engine

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the Amazing Audio Engine but you can definitely do what you're asking using Core Audio. If you've read all the AAE documentation and are still stuck then I'd suggest learning more about Core Audio. [C Adamson's text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007R3U9W2) is very good for this.

You might also look at Apple-supplied sample code like [Mixer Host](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html) or [this sample code](https://github.com/tkzic/audiograph).

Lastly, [here's sample code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12216224/conferences/vtm11/VTMAUGraphDemo.zip), again from C. Adamson, that demos both Remote IO and the AUFilePlayer unit.

Hope that helps.